# Oracle Apex add db link in processing query

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have an IG including the different database details.

In the processing I need to push data from one db to another.

Ex:

```
Declare
l_cnt NUMBER;
Cursor crec is select db_name,db_id,description from db_details;
Begin
FOR cur in crec LOOP
select count(*) into l_cnt from db_details where db_name= cur.db_name;
IF l_cnt =0 THEN
Insert into **DB_DETAILS@cur.db_name** (DB_NAME,DB_ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES(cur.db_name,db_id,description);
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

The part in bold is obviously throwing error.

P1_DATABASE holds the current database name which is selected from dropdown.

Comment: **Which** error?

Comment: table or view does not. exist. But it does.  Ex: TESTDEV is DB Name. So select * from DB_DETAILS@TESTDEV exists. So i want to understand whether logically the processing code is wrong or is it sometihng else

Answer (score 1):

Right, as you commented, that table doesn't exist because you have to use **dynamic SQL**. You can't reference database link that way, just by naming it via cursor variable.

Furthermore, there's no point in checking `l_cnt` because cursor won't return non-existent rows anyway, so `l_cnt` would ALWAYS be greater than `0`.

Here's a different option. Note that all strings have to be enclosed into single quotes (that's `chr(39)`); I presumed that these are `db_name` and `description`.

```
DECLARE
   l_str  VARCHAR2 (500);
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r IN (SELECT db_name, db_id, description FROM db_details)
   LOOP
      l_str :=
            'insert into db_details@'
         || cur_r.db_name
         || '(db_name, db_id, description)'
         || ' values ('
         || CHR (39)
         || cur_r.db_name
         || CHR (39)
         || ', '
         || cur_r.db_id
         || ', '
         || CHR (39)
         || cur_r.description
         || CHR (39)
         || ')';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

---

Demo; I'm not inserting anything over a database link but into a local table. The only difference is a missing `@` character in line #7.

Sample tables: source:

```
SQL> select * from db_details;

DB_NAME         DB_ID DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------- ---------------
dba                 1 test
```

Target:

```
SQL> desc db_detailsdba;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DB_NAME                                            CHAR(3)
 DB_ID                                              NUMBER
 DESCRIPTION                                        CHAR(4)

SQL> select * from db_detailsdba;

no rows selected
```

Code:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_str  VARCHAR2 (500);
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT db_name, db_id, description FROM db_details)
  5     LOOP
  6        l_str :=
  7              'insert into db_details'    --> I removed @ here
  8           || cur_r.db_name
  9           || '(db_name, db_id, description)'
 10           || ' values ('
 11           || CHR (39)
 12           || cur_r.db_name
 13           || CHR (39)
 14           || ', '
 15           || cur_r.db_id
 16           || ', '
 17           || CHR (39)
 18           || cur_r.description
 19           || CHR (39)
 20           || ')';
 21
 22        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
 23     END LOOP;
 24  END;
 25  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM db_detailsdba;

DB_NAME         DB_ID DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------- ---------------
dba                 1 test

SQL>
```

---

So, yes - now it works.

Comment: I have another similar query but there I need the dynamic sql in IG query as pl/sql function returning body. How can i write select query ? Shall i use for loop there as well to pull db links that are stored in another column? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77076615/oracle-apex-dynamically-add-dblink-to-query-in-grid-using-pl-sql-dynamic-content

Comment: From my point of view, interactive grid is OK for purposes that require *spreadsheet-like* layout, allowing users to both view and modify displayed data. For anything else - such as processing - I really wouldn't choose interactive grid. I'd probably create a stored procedure (which does that *processing* part of the job) and call it by pressing a button in Apex application. Therefore, I wouldn't know what to suggest regarding question you posted in a comment (apart from what I said - that I wouldn't do that in an IG).