# Oracle Apex Dynamically add dblink to query in Grid using PL/SQL dynamic content

Tags: oracle-apex, dynamic-sql

I have an Apex page which selects databases from drop down:

```
All
DBDEV
DBTEST
POCTEST
```

The IG Query currently is:

```
  select db_name, description,enable,allow , 
(select database_link from links a where a.db_name = b.db_name) link_db from db_details b;
```

I need to add another column that compares another similar table in a different schema and returns value Y/N.

So query needs to be something like:

```
select db_name, description,enable,allow , 
select case when exists 
(select db_name,description_enable,allow from db_details@**db_link** d 
    where d.db_name=b.db_name 
    and d.description=b.description
 and d.enable=b.enable and d.allow =b.allow) 
    THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END FROM DUAL AS VALIDITY,
(select database_link from links a where a.db_name = b.db_name) link_db 
from db_details b;
```

For the VALIDITY column, the @**db_link** needs to be the link_db column value that needs to be passed dynamically.

So if link_db value is TSTDEV, the validity column query should pass dblink as  @TSTDV.

Can i please get some guidance on using pl/sql dynamic content which seems to be the only solution for the above?

If i have not been explain to properly please let me know and i will share more details.

Comment: You asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77042458/oracle-apex-add-db-link-in-processing-query Question was answered and upvoted. I suggest you continue that thread

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle Apex add db link in processing query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77042458/oracle-apex-add-db-link-in-processing-query)

Comment: Actually that was for processing part for inserting rows. Here's it's a different requirement. So how i'd put this as dynamic query in interactive grid is my doubt..

Comment: Logic is similar. Use type "Function Body returning SQL Query"

Comment: Ok But here i have the dblink value in another column. To pass it do i need the for loop? Sorry i am not very confident with dynamic sql

Answer (score 0):

If the link names rarely change you could hardcode them:

```
select b.db_name, 
       b.description,
       b.enable,
       b.allo, 
from db_details b
     left outer join db_details@DBDEV l1 ON b.db_name = l1.db_name
     left outer join db_details@DBTEST l1 ON b.db_name = l1.db_name
     left outer join db_details@POCTEST l1 ON b.db_name = l1.db_name;
```

else I would load the data from the tables that are over the dblink in a collection and join to that in your query.

Upon further thought... it seems you are only pulling very small amounts of data from the databases over the db link. Would it not make more sense to have a procedure running on page load that fetches the rows from the remoted dbs into a local table ? It would save you a lot of time