# Oracle Apex remote db link connection description for remote database not found

Tags: oracle-apex, remote-access

I have a pl/sql processing code part in Apex page which is calling db links using variable.

Ex:

```
Cursor crec is select link from db_links;
Begin
l_sql := 'insert into emp values select * from emp_dets@db_link';
For rec in crec
LOOP
l_replace := replace (l_sql,db_link,rec.link)
Execute l_replace into l_sql;
END LOOP;
END;
```

When it is run it gives the error connection description is not found in the line where link is being replaced.

The available db link can be accessed.

select * from emp_dets@DEV ; I run and it can be accessed.

Still process gives the error.

What could be the possible reasons?

Comment: Weren't you already told (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77042458/oracle-apex-add-db-link-in-processing-query) how to do that?

Comment: I need to do it differently now. The problem isn't in the way of doing it. The remote link isn't being accessed with the mentioned way. So need help with the probable causes.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the possible reasons?

You are using invalid syntax:

- You are missing a `DECLARE` statement at the start of your PL/SQL block and have not declared the variables `l_sql`, `l_replace` or `db_link` (but that last one you probably did not intend to be a variable).
- `replace (l_sql,db_link,rec.link)` is looking to replace text in the `l_sql` variable that contains the value of a `db_link` variable with the value of `rec.link` from the cursor. You do not include a `DECLARE` statement but I am assuming that `db_link` is not a variable and should be a string literal
  `'db_link'`.
- You are missing the `;` statement terminators following the `replace`.
- You want `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and not `EXECUTE`.
- Your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement does not return anything so you do not need an `INTO` clause.
- In an `INSERT` statement you want either a `VALUES` clause or a `SELECT` clause but not both.

Your code would be:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_replace VARCHAR2(200);
  l_sql     VARCHAR2(200);
  CURSOR crec IS select link from db_links;
BEGIN
  l_sql := 'insert into emp select * from emp_dets@db_link';
  FOR rec IN crec
  LOOP
    l_replace := replace(l_sql, 'db_link', rec.link);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_replace;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or more simply:

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (select link from db_links)
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into emp select * from emp_dets@' || rec.link;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```